# How do I get the Cloudflare url in an Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

My company has a pipeline that deploys to Cloudflare using the `wrangler pages deploy` command. This deploys to a url of the following format: https://[some 8 digit code].[project name].pages.dev/.

How do I retrieve that url in my Azure DevOps Pipeline and put it in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pipeline, you can add a Bash task to execute the following command lines:

1. Execute '**`wrangler pages deploy`**' command and save its output content into a text file.
2. Execute the '**`sed`**' command with regular expression to extract the URL from the content of text file.
3. Execute the logging command '[**SetVariable**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)' to set the a pipeline variable with the value as the URL.

```bash
wrangler pages deploy > deploy_output.txt
pageUrl=$(sed -n -e 's/^.*\(https:\/\/[[:alnum:]]\{8\}\.myproj\.pages\.dev\)$/\1/p' deploy_output.txt)
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=url;]$pageUrl"
```

[image]

Comment: @Shoreline, Is there any update from you?

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. Apologies for the long wait. When I initially copypasta'd the answer I had not spotted that I needed to change the `.myproj` part of the regex, so it was not matching. Call me Mr Silly.